# Allure Jenkins Report does not shows 'setup' and 'teardown' methods in steps

Tags: jenkins, allure

I have a Maven project. I am using testng framework(v 6.14) along with allure reporting (v2.8.1) for testing our application. On triggering the build locally, it shows 'Setup','Reusable' and 'TearDown' methods in allure report.
Next I configured it with Jenkin and upon job completion, the allure reports does not displays 'SetUp' and 'TearDown' method.It shows only the reusable methods used for executing the test.

One difference I found is locally I use '`allure serve <dir of allure-results>`' command but jenkins uses '`allure generate <path to allure result folder> -c -o <dir>`.

Comment: I found out that Jenkin uses 'ru.yandex.qatools.allure' allure comand line. I generated the reports and hosted them to a web server and 'setup' / 'tear down' method was not captured. Seems like an issue with the Allure command line tool.

Comment: In my case, Test body is not shown in Jenkins report.